# How I can use an input field as a search field and store data for signup?

Tags: reactjs, api, react-hooks

I need help to do two functions for an input field. First I need to use that input field to search if the data that I want to send existe in the database, and second I just need to store data for signing up. I have tried to do it but I did manage to make those both functionalities to work in that same input field. The search is working, but when I try to signup all the fields are saving the data except that specific field. As you can see in the screen shoot below. Can somebody give me some advises on how to implement this? Thanks a lot.
here is what I am trying to do:

[image]

**App:**

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="container searchApp">
        <h2 className="title is-2 has-text-centered">
          Get CVR data into your own system
        </h2>

        <Signup />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Search:**

```
    function Search({ search }) {
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState("");

  const handleOnChange = (e) => {
    const text = e.target.value;
    setSearchText(text);
  };

  const handleEnterKeyPressed = (e) => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      search(searchText);
      setSearchText("");
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        variant="standard"
        required
        onChange={handleOnChange}
        onKeyPress={handleEnterKeyPressed}
        value={searchText}
        placeholder="Company CVR"
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Infos:**

```
const Infos = ({ company }) => {
  return (
    <div className="result">
      <h3>{company.name}</h3>
      <ul>
        <li key={company.vat}>Company CVR {company.vat}</li>
        <li>Address: {company.address}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**Signup:**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Search from "./Search";
import Infos from "./Infos";
import axios from "axios";

const initialState = {
  cvrNumber: "",
  fullName: "",
  userPosition: "",
  email: "",
  password: "",
};

const Signup = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(initialState);
  const [result, setResult] = useState();

  const search = async (text) => {
    const response = await axios.get("https://cvrapi.dk/api", {
      params: { search: text, country: "dk" },
    });

    setResult(response.data);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(data);
    setData(data);
  };

  const handleChange = (e) =>
    setData({ ...data, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

  return (
    <div>
      <h4>Signup</h4>

      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Search
          name="cvrNumber"
          placeholder="Company CVR"
          onChange={handleChange}
          search={search}
          company={result}
        />
        <div>{result && <Infos company={result} />}</div>

        <h4>Register your user Login</h4>
        <input
          name="userPosition"
          placeholder="User Position"
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <input
          name="fullName"
          placeholder="Full Name"
          onChange={handleChange}
        />

        <input
          name="email"
          placeholder="Email Address"
          onChange={handleChange}
          type="email"
        />
        <input name="password" placeholder="Password" onChange={handleChange} />

        <button type="submit">Sign Up</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simple forgot to pass `onChange` from your `SignUp` component to the `Search` component. Fix your `Search` component like so

```
// Destructure onChange too! 
function Search({ search, onChange }) {
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState("");

  const handleOnChange = (e) => {
    const text = e.target.value;
    setSearchText(text);
    // Call onChange
    onChange(e);
  };

  const handleEnterKeyPressed = (e) => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      search(searchText);
      setSearchText("");
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      Search
      <input
        // Provide a name for this input
        name="searchText"
        variant="standard"
        required
        onChange={handleOnChange}
        onKeyPress={handleEnterKeyPressed}
        value={searchText}
        placeholder="Company CVR"
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Rishabh Singh for this valuable advices, it worked